How to rename http metric in OTEL JS
I have many java applications and they have been instrumented with Micrometer(SpringBoot natively support it). They send metric to OTLP Mimir.
I have a NodeJS application which I want to instrument with OTEL and want same naming semantic convention on both.
I did some research and figured out it is impossible to do on Micrometer here. Therefore, I want to configure NodeJS application to emit metric with custom names.
One such metric is:

OTEL emits http.server.request.duration.count
Micrometer emits http.server.requests.count

Tags are also different.
Here is my code so far:
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";
import { NodeTracerProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node";
import { AlwaysOnSampler, BatchSpanProcessor } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base";
import { Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources";
import { ATTR_SERVICE_NAME } from "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions";
import { ExpressInstrumentation } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express";
import { HttpInstrumentation } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http";
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc";
import { BatchLogRecordProcessor, LoggerProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-logs";
import logsAPI from "@opentelemetry/api-logs";
import { OTLPLogExporter } from "@opentelemetry/exporter-logs-otlp-grpc";
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from "@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc";
import { MeterProvider, PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics";

export const setupOpenTelemetry = (serviceName: string) => {
  const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
      [ATTR_SERVICE_NAME]: serviceName
    }),
    sampler: new AlwaysOnSampler()
  });

  // const exporter = new ConsoleSpanExporter();
  const otlpExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter();
  //provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));
  tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(otlpExporter));
  // Initialize the OpenTelemetry APIs to use the NodeTracerProvider bindings
  tracerProvider.register();

  const metricExporter = new OTLPMetricExporter();
  const meterProvider = new MeterProvider({});

  meterProvider.addMetricReader(
    new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
      exporter: metricExporter,
      exportIntervalMillis: 1000
    })
  );
  // To start a logger, you first need to initialize the Logger provider.
  const loggerProvider = new LoggerProvider();
  // Add a processor to export log record
  // loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(new ConsoleLogRecordExporter()));
  loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(new BatchLogRecordProcessor(new OTLPLogExporter()));
  logsAPI.logs.setGlobalLoggerProvider(loggerProvider);

  registerInstrumentations({
    tracerProvider,
    meterProvider,
    instrumentations: [
      // Express instrumentation expects HTTP layer to be instrumented
      new HttpInstrumentation(),
      new ExpressInstrumentation()
    ]
  });
};


